# How to insert into one table null value and select * from another table in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one extra (id AI) column in B table, How can I fill all the data from A table and set id as null?

```
Table A
|---------------------|------------------|
|          id         |  EmployeeName    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           1         |       ABC1       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           2         |       ABC2       |
|---------------------|------------------|
|           3         |       ABC3       |
|---------------------|------------------|

Table B
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|          id          |       empid         |  EmployeeName    |    
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|                      |                     |                  |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|                      |                     |                  |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|                      |                     |                  |
|----------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

Here we only have 2 columns but say we have many columns corresponding to a dynamic query.

here is the query I am trying

```
insert into B (select null, * from A);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This way should do it:

```
INSERT INTO B (SELECT NULL, A.* FROM A);
```

You just need to append the table name `A.` to the Asterix.

Comment: I was missing on such a minor detail, this is an awesome solution. This way I can create a dynamic query.

Answer (score 3):

You can try inserting only to the specified columns in B table. Then the column which is not present automatically gets populated as NULL

```
INSERT INTO table2 (empid,EmployeeName)
SELECT Id,EmployeeName
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

Comment: I am writing a dynamic query which should work for more than one set of tables. so that I dont have to specify column names.